# adding an item to a list or create a new list and add in the same line in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, dictionary

I have this code snippet which works

```
for (let [num, freq] of map) {
    let values = (bucket[freq] || new Array()) ;
    values.push(num);
    bucket[freq] = values
}
```

bucket is an array of lists
it's iterating over `map`, checking if there is a list in the spot of `freq`, if not, it creates a new list, pushes `num` to the list, and pushes the list back to `bucket[freq]`.

When I tried to do it in one line, like this

```
for (let [num, freq] of map) {
    bucket[freq] = (bucket[freq] || new Array()).push(num) ;
}
```

then bucket didn't update correctly. I can't understand what is the difference between the two approaches

I tried to write both versions, only the first worked, the other gave me incorrect answers

Comment: Issue is because `array.push()` returns the length of the resulting array as an integer, not the array itself.

Comment: As @RoryMcCrossan mentioned, push returns a new length, no the added element. You can go with two following options:
`for (let [num, freq] of map) {bucket[freq] = bucket[freq] ?? [];bucket.push(num);}`


`for (let [num, freq] of map) {bucket[freq] = (bucket[freq] ?? []).concat([num]);}`